# How to use glob to read limited set of files with numeric names?

Tags: python, path, glob

How to use glob to only read limited set of files?

I have json files named numbers from 50 to 20000 (e.g. 50.json,51.json,52.json...19999.json,20000.json) within the same directory. I want to read only the files numbered from 15000 to 18000.

To do so I'm using a glob, as shown below, but it generates an empty list every time I try to filter out for the numbers. I've tried my best to follow this link (https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
>>> directory = "/Users/Chris/Dropbox"
>>> read_files = glob.glob(directory+"/[15000-18000].*")
>>> print read_files
[]
```

Also, what if I wanted files with any number greater than 18000?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are using the glob syntax incorrectly; the `[..]` sequence works *per character*. The following glob would match your files correctly instead:

```
'1[5-8][0-9][0-9][0-9].*'
```

Under the covers, `glob` uses `fnmatch` which translates the pattern to a regular expression. Your pattern translates to:

```
>>> import fnmatch
>>> fnmatch.translate('[15000-18000].*')
'[15000-18000]\\..*\\Z(?ms)'
```

which matches *1* character before the `.`, a `0`, `1`, `5` or `8`. Nothing else.

`glob` patterns are quite limited; matching numeric ranges is not easy with it; you'd have to create *separate* globs for ranges, for example (`glob('1[8-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') + glob('2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')`, etc.).

Do your own filtering instead:

```
directory = "/Users/Chris/Dropbox"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext != '.json':
        continue
    try:
        number = int(basename)
    except ValueError:
        continue  # not numeric
    if 18000 <= number <= 19000:
        # process file
        filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

Comment: What if I only wanted read files after lets say 18000. Do you have any suggestions here?

Comment: How high do the numbers go? `glob` is really quite limited; all filenames are read from the directory then filtered. You can always do your own filtering instead.

Comment: Well, files are being added as time goes on. About 50 files are generated per day and I'm on file 19000. I'm having trouble implementing 18000 to 29000 with this: "/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*", since I don't want 10000 to 18000

Comment: @Chris: `glob` is really not suited to that task.

Answer (score 5):

Although it hardly counts as beautiful code, you could implement your own filtering as follows:

```
import os, re
directory = "/Users/Chris/Dropbox"
all_files = os.listdir(directory)

read_files = [this_file for this_file in all_files 
                if (int(re.findall('\d+', this_file)[-1]) > 18000)]

print read_files
```

The crucial line here (should) iterate through each file name in the directory (`for this_file in all_files`), pull out a list of number segments in that file name (`re.findall('\d+', this_file)`), and include it in `read_files` if the last of these number segments, as an integer, is greater than 18000.

I think this will break on files with no integers in the name, so user beware.

---

**Edit:** I see the previous answer has been edited to include what looks a much better thought out way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited @martineau's code, as I was getting an error with my files, where the regex was returning an empty array (perhaps because I'm using python 3?).  I've also changed the output to be separated by spaces so it can be used in the linux command line for example:

```
cp `python readfiles.py` mydir
```

Backticks execute the command inside them and insert its output in the command line. This does assume that there are no spaces in the filenames returned.

Here's the modified code:

```
Import os, re
directory = "."
all_files = os.listdir(directory)

read_files = [this_file for this_file in all_files 
    if re.search(r'\d+', this_file) and int(re.findall(r'\d+', this_file)[-1]) > 18000
]

print(' '.join(read_files))
```