# Read a subset of files in a directory

Tags: python

I have a directory of files in a directory, named like:

```
tx01.data
tx02.data
tx03.data
```

When I call this module from the command line, I want to pass in an argument to read only a subsetted range of these files, e.g. tx01.data and tx02.data (it will always be a consecutive range, not a random selection of files).

I'm currently using `glob` to read in all of the files in the directory. From what I've found, `glob` doesn't really play well with subsetting. The closest I found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735529/how-to-use-glob-to-read-limited-set-of-files-with-numeric-names).

Is there a better way to read a subsetted range, that can be passed in from the command line?

Comment: What about something along the lines of `$(ls | head -n | tail -n)`

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what "subset" means.  How do you determine which files are in the subset?  Is it based on the name?  In your example, is `tx01.data` chosen because it has `01` in the name, or because it's the first file, or some other reason?

Comment: @jaslibra Could you expand on that? How would that work as an argument that's passed into a python script?

Comment: Also, why don't you just build a list of strings with the files you want?

Comment: @JohnGordon - A subset would be something like files 00-05, and then 06-10

Comment: Are the other portions of the filename constant?  i.e. they always begin with `tx` and end with `.data`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, the other parts are always constant.

Comment: You could use shell wildcards: `python myscript.py tx0[0-5].data`

Comment: That's an interesting idea. And then just convert the string to a list within python?

Comment: Also, does that work for numbers greater than 9?

Comment: The shell would expand the wildcard into all matching filenames.  Your python script would receive each individual filename in `argv`.  Well, in Unix it would; I'm not sure about DOS/Windows...

Comment: Yes, it can work with higher numbers, but you'd need a slightly different wildcard pattern.

Comment: What would that slightly different pattern be? Also, would I need to know how many `argv`s it's expanding to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job for you:

```
import argparse
import re
from os import listdir

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some files.')
    parser.add_argument("--range", type=str, help='file range (i.e. 0-100)', default='0-100')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
        file_range = list(map(int, args.range.split('-')))
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception('Invalid parameter format...\n%s' % e)

    dir_files = listdir('.')
    matches_list = list(map(lambda x: re.match(r'm([0-9]+)\.data', x), dir_files))
    files = [x.group() for x in matches_list if x and (file_range[0] <= int(x.groups()[0]) <= file_range[1])]
    print(files)
```

The command should look like:

python script.py --range 0-200

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to pass two number at command line to tell the range:

*choose.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    first, last = sys.argv[1:]
    pattern = re.compile(rf'tx0?[{first}-{last}]\.data$')
    # pattern = re.compile(r'tx0?[{}-{}]\.data$'.format(first, last))
    for p in Path().glob('*'):
        if pattern.match(p.name):
            print(p.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

$ python3 choose.py 2 4

```
tx02.data
tx03.data
tx04.data
```

Comment: Interesting! The dash between `{first}` and `{last}` is giving me a compile error.

Comment: @Adam_G python3.6+ is required!