# Glob files for a range of numbers

Tags: python, glob

I have a directory of files with names 10.txt, 11.txt .. 29.txt, 30.txt

How can I select files 12 to 21?

Ive tried:

```
glob.glob('path/[12-21].txt')
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735529/how-to-use-glob-to-read-limited-set-of-files-with-numeric-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glob is good if you do not know what file names and just need a rough pattern, however, in your case you do know so you might not need to use `glob`.

It would be better to simply generate your expected list of files and check if they exist eg

```
from os.path import isfile

# Generate a list of expected file names
expected_files = ["path/{}.txt".format(i) for i in range(12, 22)]

# Filter the list to just the files that actually exist.
actual_files = [f for f in expected_files if isfile(f)]
```