# Python: How to read globbed CSV files in batches, and store in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I have a large number of *.csv* files in a folder. All *.csv* files have the same column names. The below code merges all the *.csv* files. But I have to merge the top 10 *.csv* files in one DataFrame after that 11 to 20 in the next step and so on... The [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735529/how-to-use-glob-to-read-limited-set-of-files-with-numeric-names) and [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066931/glob-files-for-a-range-of-numbers) are suitable if file names are numeric but in my case file names are not following any pattern.

```
# Merge .csv files in one place
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd  

path = r'D:\Course\Research\Data\2017-21'  
print(path)
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f,encoding='utf8',error_bad_lines=False) for f in all_files)
merged_df = pd.concat(df_from_each_file)
```

Comment: Write a simple while loop to 10, at the end of the loop write the output, and if the count is 10, reset the count to zero. Carry on until all files in the list are exhausted.

Comment: I couldn't implement the method you suggested, will you please share the full working code?

Comment: What happens with the `merged_df` dataframes: Should they be processed immediately, collected somewhere, etc.?

Comment: For an instance, after merging, just count and print all the rows of `merged_df`. Like  `print(merged_df.shape[0])`

Comment: @MurariMahaseth - Of course. Please see the answer below, which is even more simply implemented than my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment above, here is a more simple solution.

- All required CSV files are collected by `glob`. In its current state, the list is *not* sorted, but can be according to your requirements
- The list of files is iterated in 10-file-chunks
- Each chunk is read and concatenated together into the merged DataFrame: `dfm`
- Do whatever you like with the DataFrame
- The `to_csv` example uses a random 4-byte hex string to ensure uniqueness* over the output files

*Note: This is *not* guaranteed uniqueness, but will suffice with the 50 sample data files I was using.

#### Sample code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

dfm = pd.DataFrame()
files = glob(os.path.join('./csv2df', 'file*.csv'))  # 50 CSV files

for i in range(0, len(files), 10):
    dfm = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f) for f in files[i:i+10])
    # Do whatever you want with the merged DataFrame.
    print(dfm.head(10), dfm.shape)
    print('\n')
    # Write to CSV?
    dfm.to_csv(f'./csv2df/merged_{os.urandom(4).hex()}.csv', index=False)
```

#### Output:

The following is a sample output from the print statements:

```
      col1     col2     col3     col4
0   file49   file49   file49   file49
1  data1.1  data1.2  data1.3  data1.4
2  data2.1  data2.2  data2.3  data2.4
3  data3.1  data3.2  data3.3  data3.4
4  data4.1  data4.2  data4.3  data4.4
5  data5.1  data5.2  data5.3  data5.4
0   file30   file30   file30   file30
1  data1.1  data1.2  data1.3  data1.4
2  data2.1  data2.2  data2.3  data2.4
3  data3.1  data3.2  data3.3  data3.4 (60, 4)
    
...
      col1     col2     col3     col4
0   file14   file14   file14   file14
1  data1.1  data1.2  data1.3  data1.4
2  data2.1  data2.2  data2.3  data2.4
3  data3.1  data3.2  data3.3  data3.4
4  data4.1  data4.2  data4.3  data4.4
5  data5.1  data5.2  data5.3  data5.4
0   file42   file42   file42   file42
1  data1.1  data1.2  data1.3  data1.4
2  data2.1  data2.2  data2.3  data2.4
3  data3.1  data3.2  data3.3  data3.4 (60, 4)
```

#### CSV file list:

```
merged_5314ad49.csv
merged_5499929e.csv
merged_5f4e306a.csv
merged_74746bd8.csv
merged_b9def1d6.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. In the above solution, in line number 6, I replaced `'file*.csv'` with `'*.csv'` then it worked for me. The solution provided by you and another solution given by @Timus, both worked well for me.

Comment: @MurariMahaseth - Excellent, glad it’s working for you.  My pleasure.  Interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion that is using [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from the standard library module `itertools` to fetch chunks of up to 10 files:

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import islice
import pandas as pd

csv_files = Path(r"D:\Course\Research\Data\2017-21").glob("*.csv")
while True:
    files = list(islice(csv_files, 10))
    if not files:
        break
    dfs = (pd.read_csv(file) for file in files)
    merged_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    # Do whatever you want to do with merged_df
    print(merged_df)
```

(I'm also using the standard library module [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) because it's more convenient.)